Questions about having proxy with spring cloud and micro-service with spring webflux together in a cluster
We have a proxy server implemented in spring cloud using reactive. I am trying to add a new micro-service in our cluster. The requests are going to be served first by our reactive proxy service and then served by my new micro-service. My questions are the followings;
Do I need to use spring webflux in my new micro-service so that the proxy can continue work in reactive mode. I know that in order to get performance in reactive, I need to follow and fulfill four rules of reactive that all the pipeline needs to be reactive end to end. Since our proxy service is working in reactive mode, do I need to write my new micro-service in reactive mode as well? Is there any change in http request protocols when reactive API is used?
Let's say I decided to write my new micro-service using spring webflux and I cannot deliver the end to end reactive pipeline since my database client is not reactive. Event if the API is not end to end reactive, does the spring webflux still provide some benefits.
Let's say I use new spring boot with version 3.2.5 without spring web flux and decided to go with virtual threads with spring.threads.virtual.enabled: true. In that point, my new micro-service is not reactive, but does it hurt our proxy service performance? Since proxy is reactive and new micro-service is not reactive, instead it is utilizing virtual threads, do it cause a performance issues? Do I have to use virtual threads with spring webflux? Do I need to implement my controllers such that they returns Mono or deferredResults with virtual threads used instead of tomcat threads?
Thanks a lot.
I have a couple of questions about spring cloud and spring webflux. I know spring webflux uses reactive and a new version of spring cloud is implemented in reactive. Before deciding the final framework, I want to get spring community opinion.

Any service behind the proxy does not need to be webflux, in fact it doesn't even need to be Java. It just needs to speak http

Does proxy add anything to this reactive picture? Depends on the proxy, but my first guess is none. The fact that it is accessed through HTTP does not change anything. So if your new microservice is not reactive, then the entire pipeline is not - performance loss being more complex question. Spring Web Flux has some issues with reactiveness. As for virtual threads vs reactive, you may want to check out this.
